# Is it possible to reduce the number of delegate instances for PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#

For instance, if I have a type that implements `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and create 10 thousand instances of that type and register event handlers somewhere else.  Then there will be the matching number of delegate instances created for each event handler.  I would like to reduce memory foot print, but I am afraid it is not possible to avoid this.

I am unregistering event handlers and memory cleaned up eventually when object disposed.  However, I don't like that many instances of delegates created for each event handler.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyCollectionPropertyObserver : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields

    private IObservableList _sourceCollection;

    private readonly SynchronizedObservableHashSet<string> _propNameFilter =
        new SynchronizedObservableHashSet<string>();

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event EventHandler<PropertyObservedInfoEventArgs> ChangeDetected;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public MyCollectionPropertyObserver(IObservableList collection)
    {
        _sourceCollection = collection;
        _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += WeakEventHandler.Wrap(CollectionChanged, eh => _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= eh);

        Subscribe(_sourceCollection);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IObservableList SourceCollection
    {
        get { return _sourceCollection; }
    }

    public SynchronizedObservableHashSet<string> PropertyNameFilters
    {
        get { return _propNameFilter; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                Subscribe(e.NewItems);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                Unsubscribe(e.OldItems);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                Unsubscribe(e.OldItems);
                Subscribe(e.NewItems);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                Unsubscribe(_subscribedItems.ToList());
                Subscribe(_sourceCollection);
                break;
        }

        RaiseChangeDetected(new PropertyObservedInfoEventArgs(e.Action, e.NewItems, e.OldItems));
    }

    private void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsFilteredProperty(args.PropertyName)) return;
        RaiseChangeDetected(new PropertyObservedInfoEventArgs(sender, args.PropertyName));
    }

    private void InstanceChanged(object sender, InstanceChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsFilteredProperty(args.ChangedProperties)) return;
        RaiseChangeDetected(new PropertyObservedInfoEventArgs(sender, args.ChangedProperties));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private bool IsFilteredProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        //NOTE: It is important to perform Contains check before Count == 0.  Count locks, and typically there are filtered properties
        return PropertyNameFilters.Contains(propertyName) || PropertyNameFilters.Count == 0;
    }

    private bool IsFilteredProperty(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames == null) return false;
        //NOTE: It is important to perform Overlaps check before Count == 0.  Count locks, and typically there are filtered properties
        return PropertyNameFilters.Overlaps(propertyNames) || PropertyNameFilters.Count == 0;
    }

    private void Subscribe(IEnumerable entities)
    {
        if (entities == null) return;

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Subscribe(entity);
        }
    }

    private readonly SynchronizedObservableHashSet<object> _subscribedItems =
        new SynchronizedObservableHashSet<object>();

    private void Subscribe(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return;
        if (_subscribedItems.Contains(entity))
            return;

        _subscribedItems.Add(entity);

        var propChange = entity as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (propChange != null)
            propChange.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;

        var instChanged = entity as INotifyInstanceChanged;
        if (instChanged != null)
            instChanged.InstanceChanged += InstanceChanged;
    }

    private void Unsubscribe(IEnumerable entities)
    {
        if (entities == null) return;
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Unsubscribe(entity);
        }
    }

    private void Unsubscribe(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return;

        _subscribedItems.Remove(entity);
        var propChanged = entity as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (propChanged != null)
            propChanged.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChanged;

        var instChanged = entity as INotifyInstanceChanged;
        if (instChanged != null)
            instChanged.InstanceChanged -= InstanceChanged;
    }

    private void RaiseChangeDetected(PropertyObservedInfoEventArgs message)
    {
        var handler = Volatile.Read(ref ChangeDetected);
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, message);
    }

    private void CleanUp()
    {
        if (_sourceCollection == null) return;
        _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;
        _sourceCollection = null;
        Unsubscribe(_subscribedItems.ToList());
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            CleanUp();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that the delegate instances where the source of your memory problems?

Comment: You can avoid storing that much data only if the amount of information you need to store is reduced.  Well, is there redundancy?  For example, do all instances of the type forward property notification to a single object?

Comment: Yup, now that you are showing code we can see that your `Subscribe` method is doing exactly the "wasteful" version of many sources-one sink that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I like the suggestion.  I will change the code and use the memory profiler.  Do you mind explaining Unsubscribe suggestion you made?

Comment: Ben never mind about unsubscribe comment.  I see what you mean.  Thank you.

Comment: Scott, I used the memory profiler.

Answer (score 2):

If there is some redundancy between the event subscriptions, then yes you can dramatically reduce the number of delegate objects.  Examples:

## 10000 sources, one sink

Wasteful, because each conversion from method group to delegate creates a new delegate object, even though the target object and target method are exactly the same in all of them:

```
foreach( source in source_list )
{
    source.PropertyChanged += this.ItHappened;
}
```

Better:

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler common = this.ItHappened;
foreach( source in source_list )
{
    source.PropertyChanged += common;
}
```

## One source, 10000 sinks

Wasteful, because although the same method is called for each sink object, the delegate stores both the target and method information:

```
foreach( sink in sink_list )
{
    source.PropertyChanged += sink.ItHappened;
}
```

Better:

```
source.PropertyChanged += delegate(sender, args) {
   foreach ( sink in sink_list ) {
       sink.ItHappened(sender, args);
   }
}
```

---

Now that code has been added to the question, I can show you how to implement my suggestion.  Change

```
public MyCollectionPropertyObserver(IObservableList collection)
{
    _sourceCollection = collection;
    _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += WeakEventHandler.Wrap(CollectionChanged, eh => _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= eh);

    Subscribe(_sourceCollection);
}

private void Subscribe(object entity)
{
    if (entity == null) return;
    if (_subscribedItems.Contains(entity))
        return;

    _subscribedItems.Add(entity);

    var propChange = entity as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if (propChange != null)
        propChange.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged; // creates a new delegate object, wasteful!

    var instChanged = entity as INotifyInstanceChanged;
    if (instChanged != null)
        instChanged.InstanceChanged += InstanceChanged; // same problem, wasteful!
}
```

to

```
private readonly PropertyChangedEventHandler reusablePropertyChangeDelegate;
private readonly InstanceChangedEventHandler reusableInstanceChangedDelegate;

public MyCollectionPropertyObserver(IObservableList collection)
{
    reusablePropertyChangeDelegate = PropertyChanged;
    reusableInstanceChangeDelegate = InstanceChanged;
    _sourceCollection = collection;
    _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += WeakEventHandler.Wrap(CollectionChanged, eh => _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= eh);

    Subscribe(_sourceCollection);
}

private void Subscribe(object entity)
{
    if (entity == null) return;
    if (_subscribedItems.Contains(entity))
        return;

    _subscribedItems.Add(entity);

    var propChange = entity as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if (propChange != null)
        propChange.PropertyChanged += reusablePropertyChangeDelegate;

    var instChanged = entity as INotifyInstanceChanged;
    if (instChanged != null)
        instChanged.InstanceChanged += reusableInstanceChangeDelegate;
}
```

You should also change `Unsubscribe` to use the cached instances.